# How can values of a datatable be replaced in R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, rscript

I am creating a simple R shiny app where the user uploads a .CSV file and it renders the data table in the main panel, as well as highlights column names automatically in the 'select column' section.

**What I am looking for is:**

How can values be replaced? (from old to new values). as an example How should I modify the value 100 to 500 in the 'range' column by referencing the column name in the 'select column'?

Note: I have also included a `textInput` box to mention the old and new values.

**csv data**

```
ID  Type  Category    Range
21  A1     B1          100
22  C1     D1          200
23  E1     F1          300
```

**app.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(reshape2)
library(DT)



ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      fileInput("file1","Uplaod Data",buttonLabel = "Browse..",placeholder = "No file Selected"),
      checkboxInput("header", "Header", TRUE),
      #actionButton("Splitcolumn", "SplitColumn"),
      selectInput(inputId='selectcolumn', label='select column', ''),
      #actionButton("deleteRows", "Delete Rows"),
      textInput('oldvalue', label='Oldvalue'),
      textInput('newvalue', label='New value to replace')
    ),
    mainPanel(
      DTOutput("table1"),
   
    
  ),
  
  )
)

server <- function(session, input, output) {
  rv <- reactiveValues(data = NULL)
  
  observeEvent(input$file1, {
    file <- input$file1
    ext <- tools::file_ext(file$datapath)
    
    req(file)
    
    validate(need(ext == "csv", "Please upload a csv file"))
    
    rv$data <- read.csv(file$datapath, header = input$header)
    
    updateSelectInput(session, 'selectcolumn', 'select column', names(rv$data))
    
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$Splitcolumn, {
    rv$data <- splitColumn(rv$data, input$selectcolumn)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$deleteRows,{
    if (!is.null(input$table1_rows_selected)) {
      rv$data <- rv$data[-as.numeric(input$table1_rows_selected),]
    }
  })
  
  output$table1 <- renderDT({
    rv$data
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Why not using the  `editable` option in `renderDT`? You get editable datatables w/o the need of dfining the changing UI yourself? cf. https://yihui.shinyapps.io/DT-edit/

Comment: @thothal, I have only shown a small portion of my original CSV, which has over 1000 rows of data. I would prefer to keep a button that replaces everything with a single click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following simplified code does what you want:

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)

ui <- fluidPage(
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         selectInput("col", "Column to search:", names(mtcars), names(mtcars)[1]),
         textInput("old", "Replace:"),
         textInput("new", "By:"),
         actionButton("replace", "Replace!"),
      ),
      mainPanel(
         DTOutput("table1")
      )
   )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
   my_data <- reactiveVal(mtcars)
   
   observeEvent(input$replace, {
      req(input$col)
      dat <- my_data()
      traf <- if (is.numeric(dat[[input$col]])) as.numeric else identity
      my_data(dat %>%
                 mutate(!!rlang::sym(input$col) := 
                           replace(!!rlang::sym(input$col),
                                   as.character(!!rlang::sym(input$col)) == input$old,
                                   input$new) %>% 
                           traf()))
   })
   
   output$table1 <- renderDT(
      my_data()
   )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Some remarks are in order:

- I added a `actionButton` to allow for triggering the replacement
- I removed the upload bit, b/c it is not essential to the problem at hand (in the final app, simply assign the uploded data to `my_data`)
- I used `replace` to do the actual replacement (there ar eother options). Thus I transformed to data first to a `character` vector. If it was numeric before, I re-transform the value. There are other data types not considered yet, so some thought should go into the actuaöl replacement funciton to be as versatile as needed.

Comment: yes it works good